# How to implement complex queries with a REST api?

Tags: api, rest, ember-data

I'm building an EmberJS app using ember-data.

Some of the functionality in my app requires quite complex queries.

As an example, let's say I have three entities - students, teachers and classes. If I wanted to get a list of all the students born before 1993 that are taking classes taught by teacher X, how can I do that with a RESTful api? In plain SQL it's easy enough, but I'm unsure of the best practice for implementing this into my API.

Do I need to build a custom endpoint alongside my basic REST api?

So I'd still have:

```
GET /students (which returns all the students)
GET /students/{id} (which returns a specific student)
etc
```

But then implement the following for my 'custom' query:

```
GET /students/custom/born_before/{date}/taught_by/{teacher_id}
```

Or is there a more standardized way of doing this?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can transform your

```
GET /students/custom/born_before/{date}/taught_by/{teacher_id}
```

into

```
GET /students/?born_before={date}&taught_by={teacher_id}
```

which is just a ["query by example"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_by_Example) option: you can populate a model instance with the provided fields and make a query using them. The less fields, the broader is the search and more results to show.

This is the way [JIRA's API works](https://developer.atlassian.com/static/rest/jira/6.0.html#id160699), for example.

Comment: This is a far more standard & more practically useful solution

Comment: And the result can be cached (contrary to the solution with `POST`).

Comment: @Aurélien It can be unfortunate as well, esp if you don't want caching. My only issue with this is, for complex queries and filters this is REALLY ugly to do.

Comment: @Rahly First, you are not obliged to implement caching. Second, caching doesn't mean getting outdated data (`ETag` for example is a nice way to handle this). If implemented rightly, it just means that you don't have to compute again what you already computed.

Comment: @Aurélien no, thats the problem, someone else can implement caching, outside of you and your users control. I've seen in actual proxy environments where the proxy server ignores all caching headers and does their own "rules".  POST is the usual non caching method

Comment: How do you do huge IN clauses with this approach?

Comment: @212 See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers

Answer (score 10):

One option is to have a search endpoint on your students that you can post to.

So you might have:

```
POST /students/filter
```

The filter object that you'd POST would look something like:

```
{ BornBefore:1993, TaughtBy:123 }
```

I've also seen an option where instead of posting that, the API had a filter, and then used a query string.

I prefer the first one myself. Especially if it can be a long running process, because your POST could return an ID and/or a `rel` link to the API call the client should use to get status updates and get the results.

So then you'd `POST /Students/filter` and it would respond back with rel of `/Students/Filter/123` and your client would do periodic `GET`'s on `/Students/Filter/123` until it got the result object. Of course, for simple, short queries, you could just instantly return the result. But if it was going to take more than a second or two you could go this route.

[This book by O'Reilly](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596801694.do) has some good information on structuring ReSTful APIs.

Comment: I don't like using POST to "get" information, in my opinion that is not RESTful.

Comment: I updated my answer, to show why you'd do a post in some cases. In essence you are POSTing a search object that the server runs, and then GETting the results later. Much like you would POST an image to the server and retrieve it later.

Comment: That'd be more like `/students/filters` then - as there are many. Regardless, this is not an optimal solution for average use cases. Having to make two requests to do a simple search & storing it on the backend makes little sense.

Comment: My biggest problem with using GET is that proxy's will cache them using their OWN rules, despite any headers you may send. POST/PUT's are never cached.  Although this is rare, its still a concern when dealing with users, esp in a business setting.