# REST API structure for multiple countries

Tags: rest, api

I'm designing a REST API where you can search for data in different countries, but since you can search for the same thing, at the same time, in different countries (max 4), am I unsure of the best/correct way to do it.

This would work to start with to get data (I'm using cars as an example):

```
/api/uk,us,nl/car/123
```

That request could return different ids for the different countries (uk=1,us=2,nl=3), so what do I do when data is requested for those 3 countries?
For a nice structure I could get the data one at the time:

```
/api/uk/car/1
/api/us/car/2
/api/nl/car/3
```

But that is not very efficient since it hits the backend 3 times.

I could do this:

```
/api/car/?uk=1&us=2&nl=3
```

But that doesn't work very well if I want to add to that path:

```
/api/uk/car/1/owner
```

Because that would then turn into:

```
/api/car/owner/?uk=1&us=2&nl=3
```

Which doesn't look good.

Anyone got suggestions on how to structure this in a good way?

Answer (score 1):

I answered a similar [question before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16795999/how-to-implement-complex-queries-with-a-rest-api/16796163#16796163), so I will stick to that idea:
You have a set of elements -cars- and you want to filter it in some way. My advice is add any filter as a field. If the field is not present, then choose one country based on the locale of the client:

```
mydomain.com/api/v1/car?countries=uk,us,nl
```

This field should dissapear when you look for a specific car or its owner

```
mydomain.com/api/v1/car/1/owner
```

because the country is not needed (unless the car ID 1 is reused for each country)

Update:

I really did not expect the id of the car can be shared by several cars, an ID should be unique (like a primary key in a database). Then, it makes sense to keep the country parameter with the owner's search:

```
mydomain.com/api/v1/car/1/owner?countries=uk,us
```

This should return a list of people who own a car with the id 1... but for me this makes little sense as a functionality, in this search I'll only allow one country:

```
mydomain.com/api/v1/car/1/owner?country=uk
```

Comment: The problem is that the car id is reused for countries. For a better example you can say that the ID is the registration of the car and "ABC123" can exist in all countries.

Comment: @AxAn that's arguably a design error then - how would you deal with a result where cars from different countries have the same ID?

Comment: @AnAn Can you clarify what `/api/car/owner/?uk=1&us=2&nl=3` would do exactly, ignoring the aesthetics for a moment? Is it a *search*, or a *lookup* of one or several data records you know exist?

Comment: The problem I have is how to deal with cars from different countries with the same id. `/api/car/owner/?uk=1&us=2&nl=3` would allow me to know for which country to search for the car id. Searching for the same car (licenseplate) in all countries would then be: `/api/car/owner/?uk=abc123&us=abc123&nl=abc123`

Comment: If I do `/api/v1/car/1/owner?country=uk` then I cannot use different ids for different countries. In this example uk has id 1 but us could have id 2.